# changing attributes of Windows programs from Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, files

How can I handle the attributes (read, write, hidden ...) of an executable program of Windows (*.exe) from the Linux terminal (command line)?

thanks in advance

Update:

For further clarification, suppose I have a hidden executable in Windows (NTFS). Start with a Linux LiveCD, mount NTFS partition and I want to remove the attributes of the read and hidden executable (.exe). (just an example)

Comment: On what filesystem?

Comment: NTFS / Fat32 / ext4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the filesystem is mounted with NTFS-3G, the [`setfattr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfattr) command should let you change extended attributes, which are stored in `system.ntfs_attrib_be`.

First, query the existing attributes with [`getfattr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getfattr):

```
$ getfattr -n system.ntfs_attrib_be -e hex file.txt
# file: file.txt
system.ntfs_attrib_be=0x00000022
```

Then set the new value, removing the one(s) you don't want.  According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246322.aspx , ATTR_HIDDEN = 0x2, ATTR_ARCHIVE = 0x20.  So to remove only the Hidden bit:

```
setfattr -n system.ntfs_attrib_be -v 0x00000020 file.txt
```

There is a wrapper script called [ntfs_attr.sh](https://gist.github.com/Explorer09/ac4bf6838c271a9968b3) that may simplify this.